# Use plain javascript rather then Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, breakout

I am attempting to code the game breakout in javascript.  Currently I have it working using JQuery in several locations.  My professor does not want the class to use Jquery so I have to change the areas I use jquery to javascript.

```
function windowsize() {
WIDTH = $("#canvas")[0].width = ($(window).width()-20.5);
HEIGHT = $("#canvas")[0].height = ($(window).height()-20.5);

}

windowsize();
```

I am using this function to get reference to the canvas element and subtracting from the sides to remove the scrollbar.  (on a side note if anyone knows how to remove the scroll bar without subtracting let me know!)

I attemped the following code to get reference to the canvas, but cannot get it to work?

```
var c=document.getElementById("canvas"); 
var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
```

Here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Kinetic915/kURvf/29/

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Chrome, document.documentElement.clientWidth seems to do it for you. Or, find a 100% width element on the page and get the width of that.